# Maximum element in a tree

Tags: algorithm, scala, recursion, recursive-datastructures

I have the following ADT implementation in Scala.

How to find the maximum element in the tree? Can I introduce some helper function, and if yes, then how?

```
abstract class MySet {
  def max: Int

  def contains(tweet: Tweet): Boolean = false
}

class Empty extends MySet {
  def max: throw new NoSuchElementExeption("max called on empty tree")

  def contains(x: Int): Boolean =
    if (x < elem) left.contains(x)
    else if (elem < x) right.contains(x)
    else true
}

class Node(elem: Int, left: MySet, right: MySet) extends Set {
  def max: { ... }

  def contains(x: Int): Boolean =
    if (x < elem) left.contains(x)
    else if (elem < x) right.contains(x)
    else true
}
```

I found a solution in Haskell which feels quite intuitive can I convert it to Scala somehow?

```
data Tree a = Nil | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
maxElement Nil = error "maxElement called on empty tree"
maxElement (Node x Nil Nil) = x
maxElement (Node x Nil r) = max x (maxElement r)
maxElement (Node x l Nil) = max x (maxElement l)
maxElement (Node x l r) = maximum [x, maxElement l, maxElement r]
```

**Update**

I am not interested in copying the Haskell code in Scala instead I think Haskell version is more intuitive but because of `this` keyword and other stuff in Object oriented language. How can I write the equivalent code in object oriented style without pattern matching?

Comment: Are you shadowing the `scala.collection.Set` class? Secondary question: What exactly is the "tree"? You only have a single method that returns an integer.

Comment: A maximum element in a tree of what?

Comment: So where's the diffuculty?

Comment: Still, what is the tree? Your node is now one Int and 2 objects with a max method.

Comment: @n.m. as you can see Haskal has the pattern marching which makes it very easy to pass different arguments whereas in Scala we can't what is the  proper way to write such code in scala?

Comment: Scala has pattern matching, too, @CodeYogi, so what prevents you from porting the Haskell version...?

Comment: One method is... pattern matching. http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html

Comment: @Dirk I don't want to do pattern matching instead I am more interested into writing the recursive version in OO way .

Comment: " I don't want to do pattern matching". So the Haskell version is of no interest.

Comment: @n.m. yes, that was just an idea, I was having trouble in designing recursive algorithm in OO but when I saw haskell example it was quite clear and intuitive hence I am thinking to think about the algorithm in that style but eventually write it in OO style.

Comment: Why not use Java, then, if you don't care for pattern matching and want an OO way? I see you also have tags in JavaScript, so how would you do that with objects there? I'll start you off that your class should be declare as `Node(value:Int, left:Node, right:Node)`. I don't know why you think `MySet` is necessary

Comment: You can do it in "this style" and then throw it all away and redo it in OO style, your choice. But then you wuld be doing things twice. If you like pattern matching, use it; if not, go with OO style, but then pattern matching style won't help you. You cannot have it both ways.

Comment: @n.m. do you think it hurts if I know both ways?

Comment: @cricket_007 your attention to details is a good things but you know its not helping me here any bit. We both know that we understand the intent of the question but I think you are more keen irrelevant things.

Comment: It's perfectly OK to know it both ways, but you can't really mix the styles (or I don't know how).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tree is heterogeneous, which means that each node can be either a full node with a value, or an empty leaf. Hence you need to distinguish which is which, otherwise you can call `max` on an empty node. There are many ways:

Classic OOP:

```
abstract class MySet {
  def isEmpty: Boolean
  ...
}

class Empty extends MySet {
  def isEmpty = true
  ...
}

class Node(...) extends MySet {
  def isEmpty = false
  ...
}
```

So you do something like this:

```
var maxElem = elem
if(!left.isEmpty)
  maxElem = maxElem.max(left.max)
end
if(!right.isEmpty)
  maxElem = maxElem.max(right.max)
end
```

Since JVM has class information at runtime you can skip the definition of `isEmpty`:

```
var maxElem = elem
if(left.isInstanceOf[Node])
  maxElem = maxElem.max(left.asInstanceOf[Node].max)
end
if(left.isInstanceOf[Node])
  maxElem = maxElem.max(right.asInstanceOf[Node].max)
end
```

(`asInstanceOf` is not required if you defined `max` in `MySet`, but this pattern covers the case when you didn't)

Well, Scala has a syntactic sugar for the latter, and not surprisingly it's the pattern matching:

```
var maxElem = elem
left match {
  case node: Node =>
    maxElem = maxElem.max(node.max)
  case _ =>
}
right match {
  case node: Node =>
    maxElem = maxElem.max(node.max)
  case _ =>
}
maxElem
```

You can take it slightly further and write something like this:

```
def max = (left, right) match {
  case (_: Empty, _: Empty) => elem
  case (_: Empty, node: Node)  => elem.max(node.max)
  case (node: Node, _: Empty)  => elem.max(node.max)
  case (leftNode: Node, rightNode: Node)  =>
    elem.max(leftNode.max).max(rightNode.max)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure, still learning Scala myself, but here is two versions I came up with (which the pattern match looks like a fair translation of the Haskell code)

```
sealed trait Tree {
  def max: Int
  def maxMatch: Int
}
case object EmptyTree extends Tree {
  def max = 0
  def maxMatch = 0
}
case class Node(data:Int,
                left:Tree = EmptyTree,
                right:Tree = EmptyTree) extends Tree {

  def max:Int = {
    data
      .max(left.max)
      .max(right.max)
  }

  def maxMatch: Int = {
    this match {
      case Node(x,EmptyTree,EmptyTree) => x
      case Node(x,l:Node,EmptyTree) => x max l.maxMatch
      case Node(x,EmptyTree,r:Node) => x max r.maxMatch
      case Node(x,l:Node,r:Node) => x max (l.maxMatch max r.maxMatch)
    }
  }
}
```

Tests (all passing)

```
val simpleNode = Node(3)
assert(simpleNode.max == 3)
assert(simpleNode.maxMatch == 3)

val leftLeaf = Node(1, Node(5))
assert(leftLeaf.max == 5)
assert(leftLeaf.maxMatch == 5)


val leftLeafMaxRoot = Node(5, 
                        EmptyTree, Node(2))
assert(leftLeafMaxRoot.max == 5)
assert(leftLeafMaxRoot.maxMatch == 5)

val nestedRightTree = Node(1, 
                         EmptyTree, 
                         Node(2, 
                             EmptyTree, Node(3)))
assert(nestedRightTree.max == 3)
assert(nestedRightTree.maxMatch == 3)

val partialFullTree = Node(1, 
                         Node(2, 
                             Node(4)),
                         Node(3, 
                              Node(6, Node(7))))
assert(partialFullTree.max == 7)
assert(partialFullTree.maxMatch == 7)
```

Comment: 1) It's better instead of `case Node(x,l:Some[Node],r:Some[Node]) => List(x, l.get.max, r.get.max).max` to use `case Node(x, Some(l), Some(r)) => List(x, l.max, r.max).max`. No need for `get`s. 2) The way around `Some(Node())` is to have an `Empty` object like in OP.

Comment: I think no one is getting it, I am asking to similar logic not the exact code in scala, I mean to say how can I write equivalent object oriented code?

Comment: How is this not object oriented? I'm using objects. What are you expecting? There is only one class. I suppose you could  make a `Tree` class with a `head:Node` property. Sorry, but I don't think trees are the best way learn OO patterns. Trees teach recursion and functional programming, playing with inheritance and polymorphism teaches OO

Comment: @Kolmar I mostly meant how to make the object instantiation cleaner

Comment: @cricket_007 by object oriented I mean without pattern matching sorry if I am getting too confusing.

Comment: @CodeYogi I have added my OO solution

Comment: @cricket_007 can we avoid this check `if (left == EmptyTree) 0` and use the run time polymorphic method dispatch?

Comment: Oh, probably. I left that in before I had the max method defined on all the classes / objects / traits whatever

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use pattern matching, you will need to implement an `isEmpty` operation or its equivalent, to avoid calling `max` on an empty set.

The important thing is how the tree is organized.  Based on the implementation of `contains`, it looks like you have an ordered tree (a "binary search tree") where every element in the left part is less than or equal to every element in the right part.  If that's the case, your problem is fairly simple.  Either the right sub tree is empty and the current element is the max, or the max element of the tree is the max of the right sub tree.  That should be a simple recursive implementation with nothing fancy required.

Comment: Hi due to simplicity I have presented here a basic version of the data structure actually the data structure contains an object per node and yes you are right the tree is BST but with the different key, I need to find max based on other key. That said, the idea is very simple, find the max in left, in right and compare the `max(root, left, right)` but the issue here is the max itself takes just single implicit argument i.e. the object on which its called upon, I think I need to create an internal function which takes two arguments, right?

Comment: The max of the left or right subtree doesn't depend on anything that's not in that subtree.  You shouldn't need any extra arguments (unless you are trying to do a pure tail-recursive implementation).  You could use an extra argument on a `maxHelper` to eliminate explicit empty checks, but it's not necessary.